# Usage of "Keep Any Shape"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, figurative-language

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*keep any shape*" [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=pnR9AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=%22keep+any+shape%22&source=bl&ots=WQt5rGgMxv&sig=0CoeMpyfgu0_eBX8zBw_zC0u4Is&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iNPPVN-oOYO4oQS_pYLIDA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20any%20shape%22&f=false):

> Liquids, says Bauman, do not ***keep any shape*** for long and are constantly prone to alteration.

I looked up a dictionary, but did not find the phrase "*keep any shape*" or "*keep shape*".  I then tried finding a sense of the verb "*keep*" that would fit this usage, but found none.

Could this usage of "*keep*" be scientific lingo?

Comment: The technical terms (aka "scientific lingo") are *viscosity* (for the stress needed to make a liquid of a given thickness have different speeds on either side of the liquid) and *creep* (for the rate at which a solid deforms for a given tensile stress).  The more *viscous* the liquid, the harder it is (or the longer it takes) to get it to change shape.  The more *creep resistant* the solid, the harder it is (or the longer it takes) to get it to suffer *inelastic deformation*.  A solid will "bounce back" from *elastic deformation*, but *inelastic deformation* remains after the stress goes away.

Comment: @Jasper I understand liquid has no shape.  But, I don't understand the usage of "*keep any shape*", because I cannot find it in my dictionary.

Comment: At any given instant, a liquid *does* have a shape.  For example, a droplet, or a lake, or a crown.  (Look at some of Doc Edgerton's "stop-motion" pictures of [milk droplets](http://edgerton-digital-collections.org/?s=hee-nc-57001#hee-nc-57001).)  But **most** liquids have very low *creep resistance*, so they cannot "keep any [particular] shape [very] long".  By the way, there are some very viscous fluids that do keep their shape for a long time.  For example, the glass in a glass bottle is technically a fluid (a liquid, because it is neither a gas nor a plasma).

Answer (score 4):

No, no scientific lingo for "keep" here. It's simply definition no. 4 at [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep?showCookiePolicy=true):

> to remain or cause to remain in a specified state or condition

So, in other words, "liquids don't hold their shape".

Comment: Using the definition, the original example sentence would become "*Liquids do not* ***cause any shape remain in some state*** *for long and are constantly prone to alteration*".  Is that right?

Comment: Too complicated. Use the *first half* of the definition: "Liquids do not remain in any shape for long and..."

Comment: An example for he second half would be: "I'll keep the soup warm for you." -> I cause the soup to remain in this state/condition (by leaving the stove on).