# Usage of "Hold Its Shape"

Tags: word-meaning, figurative-language

I have a question about the usages of the verb "*hold*" [here](http://www.allure.com/beauty-trends/blogs/daily-beauty-reporter/2013/02/new-breast-implant-natrelle-holds-shape.html):

> New Breast Implant *Holds* Its Shape

I checked this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hold), but cannot find a definition that fits the usage of "*hold its shape*" in the example.  Could the example be either an error, or some sort of pun-intended usage?

Comment: Look up the verbs "retain" and "maintain" and "keep" which have similar meanings.

Comment: @TRomano So, I could write "he ***held his balance*** on the tightrope" to mean "he ***maintained his balance*** on the tightrope"?

Comment: You can "hold your balance" but "maintain your balance" and "keep your balance" are far more common. Keep is most common.

Comment: So, "*he* ***held*** *his composure*" is the same as "*he* ***kept*** *his composure*"?

Comment: :define "the same as".  *Kept his composure* is the usual collocation. "Held his composure" would be understood, but is not well attested.

Comment: @TRomano  "***keep*** *his composure*" is simply more idiomatic?  And "***hold*** *its shape*" and "***keep*** *its shape*" are equally good English?

Comment: I would say it is better to use the more idiomatic version.

Answer (score 4):

It's basically just definition 1: to have or to keep.  You could read it as

> New Breast Implant Keeps Its Shape

Comment: Definition 1 of that dictionary means to physically have something.  Doesn't sound right....

Comment: The [shape](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/shape) of something is certainly a physical attribute.

Comment: I note that two days ago, the highest voted answer to meatie's question "What does _keep its shape mean"_ was  that _Keep its shape_ means _hold its shape._  This answer seems to confirm the other  :-) http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48663/usage-of-keep-any-shape

Comment: @Adam So, I could write "he ***held his balance*** on the tightrope" to mean "he ***maintained his balance*** on the tightrope"?

Comment: So, "*he* ***held*** *his composure*" is the same as "*he* ***kept*** *his composure*"?

Comment: I would say that "held his composure" means essentially the same thing as "kept his composure", yes.  In general I would use "keep" unless there was some good reason to use "hold", though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, I think, is that your link misses this particular meaning. In this case, "hold" means "to keep or maintain in its current state", and can be either active or passive. Another example would be "the stock has held its value despite the current recession", or "a good air conditioner will hold the room temperature at a comfortable level."

Comment: Exactly.  To "hold" some attribute is to keep that attribute from changing.

Comment: So, I could write "he ***held his balance*** on the tightrope" to mean "he ***maintained his balance*** on the tightrope"?

Comment: I suspect you could, but I don't think I've ever heard the phrase, so I'd advise against it. But I admit I'm not sure. Certainly the phrase I'm familiar with for exactly this situation is "He _kept_ his balance", so the new phrase doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: So, "*he* ***held*** *his composure*" is the same as "*he* ***kept*** *his composure*"?

Comment: Yup. Exactly right. And using it with composure but not with balance - well, English is a mongrel language is all I can say.